# Suppress user input keypress while executing autogenerated keypress Python

Tags: javascript, python, keyboard, pyautogui, pynput

My problem here is I want to have any keystroke the user types execute a automatic keystroke. However, I would like only the user generated keystroke to be suppressed. I am trying to do this with `pynput` like this:

```
def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False
    elif len(words) > i:
        c.press(words[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        c.press(keyboard.Key.space)
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release, suppress=True) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I think that the problem is that the keypress call inside of the on_press() function also calls to the listener function and this creates infinite recursion. If I keep the suppressor on nothing is typed but the program keeps infinitely recursing. If I turn the suppressor off both the user keypress is executed and the autogenerated key press is executed recursively.

But if I keypress outside of the on_press() function like below it only executes if I exit the listener.

```
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release, suppress=True) as listener:
    listener.join()
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False
    elif len(words) > i:
        c.press(words[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        c.press(keyboard.Key.space)
        return False
```

Does anyone have a workaround to this?

Comment: if you want to run some code when `Listener` is running then you should put it before `listener.join()`

Comment: maybe you should use some global variable with `True`/`False` - ie `disabled` - to control when some code inside `on_release` has to be executed - `if not disabled: ... check key ...`

Comment: maybe instead of writing own code use program `AutoHotKey` on Windows or `AutoKey` on Linux. `AutoKey` is created in Python so you could also check source code - but it simply uses clipboard to send new text - and this way it has no problem with user keys.

Comment: as I remeber long time ago was similar question - and for Windows it could recognize code send by `c.press()` using some special function on Windows - because Windows was add some information about source of event. But this method didn't work on Linux.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will try your advice!

Comment: @furas. I think I learned a few things after a couple hours on this issue.

1. the listener._suppress event does not actually suppress the event, it still calls the on_press event